# PHP cURL is getting webpage without requested data, but works in Postman?

Tags: php, http, curl, post, postman

I am working on a home project and I am trying to access a webpage, WITH the data I am requesting.

It is a normal webpage that returns information depending on the POST parameters.

In postman, I set all of the POST parameters and I am getting the correct results, the webpage with a table containing the information I need.
However, if I try to do the same thing with PHP cURL, I get the webpage, but not the data that I want. Why would this be? I even tried copying and pasting the generated code postman gives, and its the same result. No data.

Is it possible that the webpage can detect I am using cURL and will not give me the data because of that?

Any help would be much appreciated.
Here is an example of my code:

```
  $ch = curl_init("schedule-url");

   $params = array(
     '__EVENTTARGET'=> '',
     '__EVENTARGUMENT'=> '',
     '__LASTFOCUS'=> '',
     '__VIEWSTATEFIELDCOUNT'=> '3',
     '__VIEWSTATE'=>'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',
     '__VIEWSTATE1'=>'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',
     '__VIEWSTATE2'=>'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',
     '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'=>'CA0B0334',
     '__PREVIOUSPAGE'=>'GE8Ox-JjHDH_Qr6VSIfSWgzxNx6fP-iAsCIvlXWSCOEmms6Jn9wAbkZ4dMGLJIbzFtGIxPv8Lpz8YpVsZDNzIwR4DD-HjpMC-Lc0AiZozmw1',
     '__EVENTVALIDATION'=>'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',
     'ctl00$hfHomePage'=>'',
     'ctl00$q'=>'',
     'interfaceID'=>'1',
     'ID'=>'-1',
     'requestType'=>'',
     'source'=>'1',
     'question'=>'',
     'ctl00$MainContent$SrearchUC$ddlTerm'=>'SS171166spring 2017',
     'POST'=>'Y',
     'Button'=>'',
     'Online'=>'',
     'ctl00$MainContent$SrearchUC$ddlSubject'=>'CSE',
     'ctl00$MainContent$SrearchUC$txtCourseNumber'=>'498',
     'ctl00$MainContent$SrearchUC$txtOnbeforeDate'=>'',
     'ctl00$MainContent$SrearchUC$txtOnafterdate'=>'',
     'ctl00$MainContent$SrearchUC$txtAtAfterTime'=>'6:00 AM',
     'ctl00$MainContent$SrearchUC$txtAtBeforeTime'=>'11:50 PM',
     'ctl00$MainContent$SrearchUC$lstDays'=>'M',
     'ctl00$MainContent$SrearchUC$lstDays'=>'Tu',
     'ctl00$MainContent$SrearchUC$lstDays'=>'W',
     'ctl00$MainContent$SrearchUC$lstDays'=>'Th',
     'ctl00$MainContent$SrearchUC$lstDays'=>'F',
     'ctl00$MainContent$SrearchUC$lstDays'=>'Sa',
     'ctl00$MainContent$SrearchUC$lstDays'=>'Su',
     'ctl00$MainContent$SrearchUC$lstLocation'=>'on',
     'ctl00$MainContent$SrearchUC$lstLocation'=>'off',
     'ctl00$MainContent$SrearchUC$lstLocation'=>'online',
     'ctl00$MainContent$SrearchUC$lstLocation'=>'study',
     'ctl00$MainContent$SrearchUC$lstLocation'=>'dubai',
     'ctl00$MainContent$SrearchUC$ddlAvailability'=>'A',
     'ctl00$MainContent$SrearchUC$txtInstructor'=>'ANY',
     'ctl00$MainContent$SrearchUC$btnSubmit'=>'Find Courses'
   );

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
     "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
   ));
   $response = curl_exec($ch);

   if(!$response)
   {
     $error = curl_error($ch);
     s($error);
   } else
   {
     print_r($response);
   }

   curl_close($ch);
```

The POST parameters I used are what I found in the chrome dev tools Network tab, under **Form Data**.

Comment: Postman also send the cookies your browser has. I don't see that you send them in this request

Answer (score 0):

You could always try to use [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) instead. It could look something like this:

```
$postData= http_build_query($params);
/// The rest of your code goes here
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
```